# Insert Image into Crystal Report from vb with xml file

Tags: c#, mysql, xml, vb.net, crystal-reports

I need to show a Image in my crystal report it's like a logo image

I have a MySql Data Base the Image is stored as a blob field
this is how I do it so far

This is my Report From

```
Public Class rpt_Form
    Private Sub rpt_Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim cls As New ClassConexion
        Dim dtEnc As DataTable = cls.p_GetDataFromSP(SomeParameter)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.Tables.Add(dtEnc)
        ds.Tables(0).TableName = "AllData"
        ds.WriteXml(CurDir() & "\Data.xml")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now I go to the Crystal Report and add a new "ADO.NET (XML) connection" I select the path to the xml that I just create and I get the table "AllData" with the fields that I have in my DataTable, I can add the fields to my report without problems but when I add the "Blob field" it is just a string field and shows a lot of numbers,

Please help me to add the image from that field

Comment: are you sure yuo are using mysql?

Comment: Yes i'm sure... why?